# How does HiveInterruptUtils.interrupt() work?

Tags: hive, interrupt

I've been reading the hive source code recently, but I'm confused by this `interrupt()`. I want to know how it interrupts the current hive command.The location of this function is in `CliDriver.processLine()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the implementation of HiveInterruptUtils http://people.apache.org/~hashutosh/hive-clover/common/org/apache/hadoop/hive/common/HiveInterruptUtils.html, find this:

```
public static void interrupt() {
    synchronized (interruptCallbacks) {
          for (HiveInterruptCallback resource : 
                       new ArrayList<HiveInterruptCallback>(interruptCallbacks)) {
            resource.interrupt();
          }
    }
}
```

That might interrupts all resources previously added to the HiveInterruptCallback list.

And also the HiveInterruptCallback, http://people.apache.org/~hashutosh/hive-clover/common/org/apache/hadoop/hive/common/HiveInterruptCallback.html#HiveInterruptCallback, is an interface.

```
public interface HiveInterruptCallback {
  /**
  * Request interrupting of the processing
  */
  void interrupt();
}
```

The previously registered resources implement HiveInterruptCallback interrupt() method, so the HiveInterruptUtils.interrupt() behavior depends on the specific resource implementation.